# @Path equivalent in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Say I have controller with a method defined like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/{user-id}/foo")
public class FooController {


    @RequestMapping("bar")
    public BarController someBarLogic() {
      //
    }
}
```

Is it possible to go further than {user-id}/foo/bar without specifying the whole root-path ? (Is there a way to relativize the path like @Path annotation in Jersey or an equivalent annotation in Spring-Boot ?)

Comment: I don't really know what "go further" means. Do you need a `@PathVariable` (look at the spring user guide for help with `@RequestMapping` features)?

Comment: I will try to make it more clear. Say I want to go further like /{user-id}/foo/bar/{some-thing}. Normally, then I would define a handler with RequestMapping(bar/{some-thing}). My question is : would I be able to call {some-thing} without specifying the path till {user-id}/foo/bar ?

Comment: you can define `@RequestMapping` as long as you want, e.g. `@RequestMapping("bar/{sth}/zoo")`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're looking for ant-style wildcards in path patterns. Have a look here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-patterns

Accordingly you can define a `RequestMapping` like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class DemoController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/bar/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getDemo() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

which will match `/foo/bar/baz`.

Ok, another example based on your comment below:

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/**/baz/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getDemo() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

This will match the same url as above, and also `/foo/bar/baz/bar/foo`

Comment: Can this handle the usecase : say I have a URL /foo/bar/baz. The servlet is mapped to /.  There is a controller with @RequestMapping("/foo"). There is a method inside this controller with @RequestMapping("/bar"). So now, there is a component that can handle /foo/bar. I also want a resource that can handle the /baz part without specifying /foo/bar in there. As in when /baz is called it should relativize the path in terms of /foo/bar.

Comment: @ajj I have updated the code snippet in the answer to use your particular example, and I've tested it too. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: `code`
@RestControl
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class DemoController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/bar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getDemo() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
`code`
@RestController
public class BazController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/baz", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getBaz() {
        return "Bazzz!";
    }
}
There is a Bazcontroller with a method mapped to /baz.I don't want to explicitly specify the mapping to the BazController as /foo/bar/baz. When it sees /baz in the URL, it should resolve /baz relative to /foo/bar.

Comment: @ajj added another example, is that it?

Comment: Unfortunately no. /baz is a separate resource. In Jersey if you call /baz, there is a way to relativize the call to /foo/bar. Is that also possible in spring boot ?

Comment: I not familiar with Jersey and I don't know what you're trying to do, and I don't know what "relativize the call" means, so I'll leave it at this. Maybe somebody else will pick this up.

Comment: So that you know what I was talking about , (if you are still interested), refer to this : [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ggrby/index.html). Search for : _resource dynamically references_.

Comment: OK, I think I get it now. Spring Boot uses a different model than Jersey. You define Controllers and map URLs onto them, it's not built around the "Resources" you return. I still believe you can do anything you want with Spring Boot, PathVariables and ant-style wildcards. And no, it will not look exactly like in Jersey, because it isn't Jersey. If you have a specific issue that you need help with, maybe post that as a question and somebody might be able to help you, but as far as concepts go, I'm afraid no more can be said here.

Comment: Yes, i had tried the example but with Spring-Boot. Certain parts were not working like the /tracks/{num} inside the CD class. Have no idea why as of now. Maybe as you said it is the fundamental difference of approach and there might be ways to do this, if not directly. If I get it working, I will post the code here for reference. For the time being, leaving it here.

Comment: I was able to alleviate this problem to an extent by using Resolvers. So, if I have a url a/{id}/b, in order to understand to which "a" b belongs to, I use resolvers in the controller method. It is not exactly jersey model, but it certainly helps in some way !